# How to run python script with multiple arguments in bash for loop?

Tags: python, bash, for-loop, multiple-arguments

I have a python script that I'd like to run in bash for loop in parallel. Python script takes multiple arguments as inputs via sys.argv[x]. For example, I'd like to run in bash for loop these lines:

```
python py_script.py a b c &
python py_script.py d e f &
python py_script.py g h i
```

How could I accomplish this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The arguments are strings and float vectors as inputs from keyboard.

Comment: And how do you read and group them?

Comment: From bash I'd normally run the script sth like this: python py_scritp.py 'MON' 1.234 [1.,2.,3.,4.]. Please also see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want achieve when running this program? If you want those files to open/run i can show you a method but otherwise i don't know. Sorry :(

Heres how to run a .py file:

```
from subprocess import call # Importing the call function

call(["python", "file.py"]) # Calling the file to open
```

Comment: I'd like to have some user friendly script in similar form to this:
args = [ [a,b,c], [d,e,f], [h,g,i] ]

for arg in args;
do python py_script.py arg &
done

Unfortunately this does not work.

Comment: okay i'll try and find a solution to your question :)